# Entered UK with a Pakistani passport and visa and leaving on Canadian

Tags: visas, dual-nationality, pakistani-citizens, canadian-citizens

I entered UK with my Pakistani passport plus short term student visa valid till February 2019. I came to UK on the day I became Canadian citizen with proof of citizenship certificate and applied for my first Canadian passport from London. 
I’m planning on going to Europe from London and then I’ll be returning to London and going to Canada few days after. So I would like to know few things:
1) since there is no exit control at London Airport which passport should I use for check in and API information?
2) which passport should I use to re enter UK from Europe since my entry stamp is on Pakistani passport. 
3) I’m travelling to Europe on Canadian since i don’t need a visa with that passport. So is it vice to tell this to immigration office Incase they ask me how did I enter Europe.

After reading posts I was planning to leave UK, showing Pakistani passport and entering API information of Canadian passport but then how will UK border find out I left. I can re enter on my Pakistani passport without any issue since ( I traveled to turkey from UK with Turkish visa on Pakistani passport last month) and didn’t even carry Canadian passport.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to break this down for each segment of your journey:

1. London -> Europe

   No exit controls in London, but your exit is recorded. I would show the Pakistani passport, and when asked for a visa, show  your Canadian passport at check-in or when asked.
2. Europe -> UK

   You can enter on  your Canadian passport without issue. I would also show my entry stamp on your Pakistani passport to the immigration officer, and your proof of departure (such as a boarding pass) and ask them if everything is okay with your record.
3. UK -> Canada

   Use your Canadian passport only.